# Back button does not work after push state

Tags: jquery, ajax, back, pushstate

The issue occurs when the user clicks the back button, I want the page to essentially reload with the previous page, but the same content continually displays.

[url removed]

Comment: I see you are calling pushState when your ajax calls update. Where are you binding into popstate?

Comment: I wasn't even aware I had to bind into popstate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've pulled your solution into this answer to help future searchers.

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    location.reload();
};
```